# Space before sentence and after sentence?

Tags: html, regex

I've got this script:

```
<input type="text" name="lastnamename" pattern="[^\s]*" title="Delete space before or after sentence!" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
```

This pattern `"[^\s]*"` shows every spaces which has been made in sentence `_Adam_Sandler_`. I need pattern which shows only `_Adam Sandler_` these spaces BEFORE SENTENCE, AND AFTER SENTENCE.

Comment: Do you mean leading and trailing spaces? `^\s*` and `\s*$`, or `^\s*|\s*$`?

Comment: ye leading and trailing spaces, but how to write correctly that - [^\s*][\s*$] ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the pattern to match a string that does NOT start with a space and does NOT end with a space:

```
^[^\s].*[^\s]$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gI9nU4/1) is great for learning about and testing your regular expressions.

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxzr3g5z/).